# Implement restful url in .net where service is implemented using IHTTPHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httphandler, restful-url

I want to implement a restful service in ASP.NET. I want it to be compatible with .Net 2.0 and IIS 5+. I am constrained to not use ASP.NET MVC or REST starter kit. By reading on internet I have learned that it can be implemented using HTTPHandlers. The problem is, the request will come in as a POST request. And I want to URL to be like:

http://abc.com/MyService/MyMethod1/
and
http://abc.com/MyService/MyMethod2/

Any workarounds for this?

Thanks,
Vamyip

Comment: Would urls in the following format be acceptable?  http://abc.com/MyService.ashx/MyMethod1/ and http://abc.com/MyService.ashx/MyMethod2/ ?

Comment: @dana I have already worked this way by putting in a default page so that the urls would be abc.com/default.aspx/MyMethod1. What I want is a more elegant solution so that the URL is completely REST like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use URL Rewriting.  This is non-trivial in IIS5.  The methods I know of are as follows:

**Method 1** - ISAPI filter

These are low-level modules that allow you to manipulate the incoming request.  Programming one of these is hairy and tough to debug.  If you go this route, you are better off using one that has already been built like [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).

**Method 2** - IHttpModule

These are managed ASP.Net modules that are easy to add/remove from your application.  Again, you are better off using a pre-built component like [UrlRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/).  The issue with using one of these, (as BrainLy mentions), is that you have to configure IIS 5 to map all incoming requests to ASP.Net as follows ([link](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/installation/windows-2000-server)):

1. Open Up IIS and Navigate to the “Home Directory Tab”
2. Select “Configuration”
3. Click “Add” and enter “C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll” in the Executable box. For the file extension, enter “.*”. Finally, make sure that “Check that file exists” is not checked.

One interesting thing to note is that ASP.Net is itself an ISAPI module :)

Once you are able to manipulate URLs using one of these tools, you can easily rewrite the RESTful urls to be handled by your default.aspx page (or whatever handler you choose to use).

Comment: Can we do this using installers? I have to deploy this at multiple locations using an installer. Many of them will already have some app or website hosted on IIS. So will it be safe to get all the requests routed to ASP.NET? Really thank you all for responding.

Comment: I believe it is possible to do some automation on IIS using WHS (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727082.aspx).  Unfortunately, this is out of my area of knowledge.  As far as mapping ASP.Net to all incoming requests, I am almost certain you can do this on a site-by-site basis.  So if you are installing at a client who has multiple websites configured, you would only want do to this for your site.

Comment: Thats great. Can you help me get more information on how to map ASP.NET to all incoming requests on a site-by-site basis? If that's possible, then I'm almost done.

Comment: Thanks @dana, I was ignoring the option of routing all requests through ASP.NET thinking that it would apply to all the sites hosted on IIS. Since it is possible to do this configuration on site-by-site basis, my problem is solved.

Comment: @vamyip - Glad you got things figured out and good luck w/ the IIS5 automation.  Like I said, it is something I have never done before, but it looks possible using windows script.

Answer (score 1):

If you can allow the restriction of only IIS 7.0 and above you could use URL Rewrite http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite to do that pretty easily.

Can I ask why is it that you need to support IIS 5+? That is an 11 year old technology that hopefully people will move out of those platforms in favor of more recent versions. Also keep in mind support for some of those platforms is ending pretty soon.

If the concern is developers running Windows XP I would point out that IIS Express includes version 7.5+ functionality and is available for all platforms Windows XP and above.

Comment: I am of the same opinion as yourself, but, I don't control over requirements :( . So have to find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be difficult to do because IIS 5 will not let you handle non ASP.NET file extensions without some additional configuration in IIS. That means you are limited to URLs ending in .aspx etc. To handle URLs like those in your examples you need to map ASP.NET to handle all URLs in IIS, implement some type of URL rewriting, or introduce some kind of hacky 404 redirection.

Once you have the correct mapping in place you can wire up an IHttpHandler, but you will have to parse the incoming request yourself to work out which is /MyService/MyMethod1/ and which is for /MyService/MyMethod2/. If your methods are simple then it is easy to do this with a regular expression.

You should start with a simple handler like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) one.